# SQL display query via tables

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to make a query to display Num, Surname, ID and Mod only for individual whom have an amount of less than 40. my main issue is linking these together as these fields are separated into 2 tables and the method of linking the Num & surname with the ID & Mod require to pass through another table to link the Num & ID.

Here are my tables

T1

```
+-----+-----+--------+
| Num | ID  | amount |
+-----+-----+--------+
| 001 | PC3 |     44 |
| 002 | PC4 |     98 |
| 004 | PC4 |     56 |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

T2

```
+-----+---------+
| Num | Surname |
+-----+---------+
| 001 | Balls   |
| 002 | Martin  |
| 004 | Grey    |
+-----+---------+
```

T3

```
   +-----+------+
   | ID  | Mod  |
   +-----+------+
   | PC3 | HTML |
   | PC4 | PHP  |
   | PC5 | CSS  |
   +-----+------+
```

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
SELECT t2.Num, t2.Surname, t3.ID, t3.Mod
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.Num = t2.Num 
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.amount = <40;
```

Comment: seems right what's the question .. error.. wrong results?

Comment: so what's the problem with that query

Comment: That Where statement should be: `WHERE t1.amount <= 40;` but other than that, this SQL statement is fine.

Comment: `[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<40' at line 5
`

Comment: @JNevill that was it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove '=' between t1.amount and the numeric value it will work then

`SELECT t1.Num, t2.Surname, t1.ID, t3.Mod
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.Num = t2.Num 
INNER JOIN t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.amount < 40`

[See it from here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)